# Click on link to change the src of an image without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html

I want to click on a link to change the source of an image. Here's what I have come up with so far :

HTML :

```
<a href = "#" id = "blabla" onclick = "changesrc(); return:false;">click</a> 
<div id = "bulb">
    <center><img src = "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\on.gif" style = "width:180px;height:270px;position:relative;top:25px;border:2px solid black;"></center>
</div>
```

JS :

```
function changesrc() {
    var work = document.getElementById('bulb');

    if (work.src.match(C:\Users\hp\Desktop\on)) {
       work.src = "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\off.gif";
    }
    else {
        work.src = "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\on.gif";
    }
}
```

I am a beginner in javascript, so please help me. According to me, on clicking the a (with text click) the function change src gets executed.that func. has a variable work. the work calls the element by id = bulb. If that variable's(work's) src matches that of the image on my desktop(with the bulb on
) then it gets changed to off else it changes to on(as if it isn't on that means it's off and so we change that).

I took help from w3schools. I looked up similar questions. I even changed work.src to bulb.src . Still cant find my mistake. Please help and tell me what's causing this!!! No jQuery please as I don't know it yet.

Comment: "*I am a beginner in java, so pls help me.*" - two things, first: this is not Java, this is JavaScript (they are not - in any way whatsoever - the same thing, or even closely related); second: being a beginner doesn't mitigate the requirements of your question, given that this site is explicitly for "[*professional and enthusiast programmers,*](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)" not beginners.

Comment: So far everyone has neglected to escape the backslashes in their answers: `'C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\on'` is what you want.

Comment: @WilliamKunkel good point :D!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.getElementById('bulb') is not an image. In your code you are changing the "src" of the `<div>`.

Change the id to the image, like:

```
<a href="#" id="blabla" onclick="changesrc(); return false;">click</a> 
<div style="text-align:center;"">
<img id="bulb" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/se/se-logo-med.png?v=d9b0b6647f17" style="width:180px;height:270px;position:relative;top:25px;border:2px solid black;">
</div>
```

And Javascript:

```
function changesrc(){
    var work = document.getElementById('bulb');

    if(work.src.indexOf('se/se-')){
       work.src = 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo-med.png?v=6f86a5fa447f';
    }
    else{
        work.src = 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/se/se-logo-med.png?v=d9b0b6647f17';
    }
}
```

**Update**:

"return" corrected: `onclick="changesrc(); return false;"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (work.src.match(C:\Users\hp\Desktop\on)) {
```

This should be matching a string?

```
if (work.src.match('C:\Users\hp\Desktop\on')) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `match` function which expects a `RegExp` as a parameter. Actually I think that in your case you could just compare the `strings`:

```
if (work.src === 'C:\Users\hp\Desktop\on') {
```